# In the summary of output of the regression analysis in R, is there a way to display categorical variable with just one coefficient

Tags: r, regression, categorical-data, categorical-encoding, variable

I am doing a linear regression analysis in R with logarithmic dependent variable. One of the control variables is categorical and describes an industry. There are 6 industries and thereby R automatically creates a separate coefficient for each Industry. However, I just want to see if that variable is significant or not and am not interested in separate coefficient for each factor.

Is there a way to program it in a way that the summary of the model just says if the influence of industry was significant for at least one factor or not?

Comment: R should be creating 6-1=5 coefficients unless you are fitting a model without an intercept..

Comment: If I understand, you want to use the *Anova* function in the *car* package.

Comment: Thats Right, R creates 6-1 coefficients but I just want 1 coefficient to tell me whether the influence of any category is significant. I don't want to know which one specfically

Answer (score 0):

It only makes sense to calculate a single coefficient for an independent variable if the following conditions are met:

1. The values of the variable are **ordered**; i.e. each increment/decrease of one value indicates an increase/decrease in the represented phenomenon.
2. The values of the variable are **equidistant**. i.e any increment of one level on the variable indicates a similar increase in the represented phenomenon.

Continuous variables often meet these criteria, but categorical variables only do in certain cases: if the categories are ordinal and equidistant (e.g., number of production facilities, income strata etc.).

I suppose your variable 'Industry' is nominal instead of ordinal, so calculating a single regression coefficient instead of separate coefficients for each of the 5 dummy-variables  would not make sense.Instead, you could consider an omnibus test to test for overall differences across categories (e.g. ANOVA).